# jquery: POST data + redirect page not working as expected

Tags: jquery, redirect

I'm trying to submit some data using POST method and redirect the page. But whenever I click on the submit button, the jquery does not load properly on the new page. 
I was able to reduce my problem to the following code. For example, If I press submit, a new page gets loaded. But Submit button doesn't give any response, and no alert box appears.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}site/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function() {
  $('#submit').click( function() {
  alert("Submit button pressed" );
  $.post("/questions/submit/", 
    {qid:1, ans:"dummy" },
    function(data) {
       $('html').html(data);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="/accounts/logout">Logout</a>
    {{ section.qid }}
    <button id="submit">Submit</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Apparently, whenever the new data is loaded into the page through jquery, jquery scripts and functions are not executed. So I have to do a "refresh" on the page, and everything works perfectly. However, in the post function, if I change 'html' to 'body', submit works just fine.

```
$('body').html(data);
```

But different pages may have different script files included. So I'm not in favor of doing this. What should be the ideal way to implement this, so that jquery functions get loaded properly?

PS: On checking the "page source", I noticed that old section.qid is present in page source. However, the browser renders the new (and apparently correct) section.qid. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reload the entire contents of `<html>` like this...you're refreshing the entire page anyway (kind of defeating the point of AJAX), why not just use a normal `<form>` and postback? It would look like this:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <a href="/accounts/logout">Logout</a>
    {{ section.qid }}
    <form method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="qid" value="1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="ans" value="dummy" />
      <button id="submit">Submit</button> 
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wish it cold be that simple. The code I've written is in highly reduced form. In actual problem, the user is allowed to submit only after the answer has been custom validated using another button.(Customer requirements :) ) . So basically yes, I'm trying to simulate "post+form+submit" html with a jquery code. Is there a way out?

Comment: @Neo - Then I would block the submit event until that button has been pressed/validated by attaching a `.submit()` handler to the `<form>`, but not writing your own postback behavior that's been working for decades :)

Answer (score 0):

you haven't redirected to a page, you're using javascript to replace everything between the `<html>` and `</html>` tags after getting the text/html from another page using AJAX.

The browser view source will generally show the original source of the page from when it first loaded. Any changed you make after that will not be reflected here. You can see the changes you've made to the elements on the page, if you use a tool like [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) for Firefox, or [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) for IE.

The reason why things seem to work when you replace contents inside the `<body>` is because you're scripts are outside the `<body>` in the `<head>` tag which gets replaced when you use `html`

what exactly are you trying to do? Maybe explaining the scenario in detail can help us help you better. What needs to happen after your form POST?

AJAX is generally used to avoid refreshing the entire page, or entire contents, instead refreshing only the elements on the page that need changing.

Comment: In actuality I'm trying to replace a html form with some jquery code, (call it simulating html post form in ajax). The reason is that I'm supposed to do some custom server side validation using another button, and only then is the submit allowed.

Comment: This isn't really accurate, it depends on the browser as to what source you're seeing.

Comment: @Nick, which browsers are the exceptions? Assuming there are, so have updated my answer.

Comment: @Neo: you need to identify what elements on the page need to be updated, after validation, and after post. Also what do you mean replace an HTML `<form>` with jQuery code? I think you're trying to replace a regular form `POST` with an ajax `POST`. I think we need to see more details and the bigger picture. What exactly does the client want to see happen? What is this complex server side validation?

Answer (score 0):

On button click call this function() below and pass the parameter, in my case I passed new to servlet

function checkforNew(){

```
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/MyController?&oper=new',
                //data: {'obj':data},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response){
                    window.location.href = response.redirect;
                }
            });
        }
```

Inside servlet you need to mention following code, for the page to redirect.

String destination = "/mypage.jsp;

```
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            JSONObject responsedata = new JSONObject();
            responsedata.put("redirect", destination);

            out.print(responsedata);
            out.flush();
```